# The line of two conjugates poles make a harmonic set

Tags: geometry

Let $A,B$ be two conjugate points respect to a circle $K$ of center $O$ and radius $k$ and let $C,D$ be the intersection points of the line $AB$ and the circle $K$.
(A and B are conjugates if the polar of A passes through B and the polar line of B passes through A).

Prove that $\{AB,CD\} = -1$.

[image]
I thought about using O as a concurrence point, so I could calculate the cross ratio based on the angles formed, but I don't get anything else about this.

Now let $T$ be the intersection point of $AB'$ and $A'B$, now $DT$ and $CT$ are tangent lines to K, because $A,B,C,D$ are collinear, therefore their polars are concurrent. I found online that this makes a harmonic set, but I don't get why. Could somebody explain?

Comment: What's your definition of conjugate points?

Comment: Two points are conjugates if their polar lines pass through each other. I.e. $P$ and $G$ are conjugates if the polar of P passes through G and viceversa

Comment: A simple image would've been of a great add

Comment: There, sorry I lack Geogebra skills, but that Paint image works I guess.

Comment: paint is always a nice path, wish you tag names in your comment next time you address somebody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Reciprocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) preserves cross ratios. This is easy to see if you consider the fact that algebraically it's just a matrix multiplication applied to the homogeneous coordinates of all points. So if I write lower-case letters for polar lines, you have

$$\{AB,CD\}=\{ab,cd\}\tag1$$

The cross ratio of four (concurrent) lines is equal to the cross ratio of the points of intersection they form with any other line (that does not pass through their point of concurrence). In particular, you get the same cross ratio if you intersect these lines with $AB$ and consdier these points of intersection:

$$\{ab,cd\}=\{BA,CD\}\tag2$$

Notice how this exchanges the order of $A$ and $B$. So if you combine $(1)$ and $(2)$ you get

$$\{AB,CD\}=\{BA,CD\}\tag3$$

and the only way to satisfy that equation with four *distinct* points is via a harmonic set.